# SQL - Group By and Filtering Between Two Dates

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I have a consumption table like this:

```
Account_ID | Product_ID | Date_Purchased | Amount_Purchased
         1 |         57 |       05/26/20 |               14
         7 |         14 |       09/18/19 |               12
        45 |         104 |      08/27/20 |                3
```

What I'm trying to do is for each `Product_ID` look at the first 30 days the product was available (assume the start date is the min of `Date_Purchased` in the consumption table for a given product) and count the number of unique `Account_ID`s that purchased >= 10 units (`Amount_Purchased`) of it, as well as the total number of unique accounts that were active in that 30-day window (where "active" means they purchased anything within those 30 days), so that I can get a percentage of active accounts that purchased at least 10 units of the product within the 30-day window.

I can do something like this to get the 30-day window for each unique `Product_ID`:

```
SELECT 
    Product_ID, 
    MIN(Date_Purchased) as Start_Date, 
    TO_CHAR(DATEADD(day, 30, Start_Date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as End_Date
FROM consumption_table
GROUP BY Product_ID
```

But I'm struggling with how to filter `Date_Purchased` within each 30-day window to then count the distinct accounts who were active, as well as the count of accounts that purchased >= 10 units. If I had only one 30-day window/product to look at, I could obviously put it in `WHERE`, but I have hundreds of `Product_ID`s. Can this be accomplished using  `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` possibly with `CASE WHEN`? Sorry if this is a pretty basic question. My desired output would look something like this:

```
Product_ID | Start_Date | End_Date | Active_During_30_Days | Purchased_10_Units | Pct
         1 |   06/18/20 | 07/18/20 |                356891 |               5467 | 0.01532
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Your code is not MySQL code.  Please tag the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT Product_ID, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN amount_purchased > 10 THEN Account_Id END) as num_big_accounts,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Account_ID) as num_accounts,
       ( COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN amount_purchased > 10 THEN Account_Id END) /
         COUNT(DISTINCT Account_ID)
       ) as ratio
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             MIN(Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_ID) as min_Start_date
      FROM consumption_table c
     ) c
WHERE Start_Date < min_Start_Date + INTERVAL '30 day'
GROUP BY Product_ID;
```

Note:  This uses standard date functions.  You'll probably need to adjust for your database.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I believe this is only counting the number of distinct accounts that purchased the Product_ID within the 30-day window. I am looking for num_accounts to be the number of accounts that purchased anything within the 30-day window (the "active" accounts). Thanks again.

Comment: @jj445 . . . Just remove the `GROUP BY` and `Product_ID` from the `SELECT`.